# Telerik Html5 Report viewer does not have commands collection

Tags: c#, html, telerik-reporting

According to the telerik documentation [Telerik Reporting Q3 2014](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/html5-report-viewer-reportviewer-properties-commands.html) , report viewer exposes all it is available commands through the commands collection, in the custom print button click i try to execute print command, but there commands property is undefined, indeed.

```
$scope.customprint = function() {
    var rv = $("#reportViewer1").data("telerik_ReportViewer");
    rv.commands.print.exec();
};
```

rv.commands -> undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I was working against Telerik Reporting Q3 2013, since the above mentioned feature has been added to Telerik Reporting Q3 2014, indeed.